# How to show/hide animated component in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have a sub-component which I'd like to show/hide in an animated way, just like Bootstrap's *collapse* component. The button which triggers visiblity is located in the outer view (not inside the sub-view).

When using the basic syntax

```
<compose view-model="edit-x" model.bind="x" show.bind="shouldShow"></compose>
```

(or the corresponding syntax with custom html element name), it works, but it just appears (not animated).

**Suggestion 1 - use Aurelia animation**

I did try to add a `class='au-animate'` with no effect (also included the aurelia-animator-css in the main.js for that).

**Suggestion 2 - Use Bootstrap**

Another possible solution could be perhaps to utilize Bootstrap, and pass in a second parameter (visible) to the component, then have the component in some way monitor that variable and call `$('.collapse').collapse('toggle')`. How would I then pass in two variables in `model.bind`? And how to monitor it? Can one use `@bindable` on a *setter*?

**Suggestion 3 - Use Bootstrap from the outside component**

Maybe the easiest would be to call `$('#subcomponentName .collapse').collapse('toggle')` from the outside view? It this ugly? I do reference elements in the sub-view from the outer view, which is maybe crossing some boundaries, but code will be small?

Comment: aurelia-animator-css only kicks in if the view is removed from the DOM, which `show.bind` not does, it only hides the element. Instead try `if.bind="shouldShow"`.

Comment: @Gusten do you want to submit this as an answer? I think it solves the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Answering my own question here, as there was more to do to get it working)*

Got this to work:

First by following @Gusten's comment about `if.bind` instead of `show.bind`.
Then by adding CSS classes for animation. 
It also seems like the animated element (the one with `au-animate` css class) must be the first element below the root `<template>` element.

So in my CSS:

```
div.test.au-enter-active {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight 1s;
  animation: fadeInRight 1s;
}
```

and then the element:

```
<template>
  <div class="test au-animate">
  ...
```

(notice the `au-animate` + my own `test` class, the latter just there for easy selection of the element)

The `fadeInRight` CSS animation is defined elsewhere in the CSS file.